# Move output files to specified folder manually

Tags: redirect, files

I found a problem using libicns's icontainer2icns command, it doesn't have an option to specify output folder but just put all extracted .icns files in current working directory.

For example, there is a file named "source.icontainer" under "/home/user/test"

```
user@localhost:/home/user$ icontainer2icns test/source.icontainer
```

Running above command will resulted in all .icns files be extracted to /home/user but not /home/user/test folder.

Is there a way to redirect all extracted files to whatever folder i specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these will work:

```
$ cd test
$ icontainer2icnssource.icontainer
```

or:

```
$ cd test; icontainer2icnssource.icontainer
```

or:

```
$ (cd test; icontainer2icnssource.icontainer)
```

That one will do what you want and leave you back in the directory you started from since it's executed in a subshell.

If you're using Bash, the next one will also do that, but it's not portable to some other shells:

```
$ pushd test; icontainer2icnssource.icontainer; popd
```